# adding event in backbone.js loses the this context

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone app that, in a function, inserts a template, and in another function, inserts a partial template into that template.  The problem is that events bind well in the first template but not the second.  Normally, I would add an event like this:

```
events:{
    'click .buttonOne': 'eventOne',  //works
    'click .buttonTwo': 'eventTwo'  //doesnt work

},
```

but, the partial templates button wont bind (no event is fired).  I'm not sure the reason for this.  So, to overcome this, I add events when the partial is inserted, like this:

```
        $("#eventTwo").click(function(){
            alert('test')
        });
```

But, I can't get the "this" object, even if I add

```
  var that = this
```

prior to the event binding.  Am I binding incorrectly?  Or is there a way I should be getting "this" that I'm not doing?

Thanks

**EDIT**:  Full code example of what is not working

My code works like this:  when the user clicks an image, an event is fired (which is a template added to the body.  The events from the original view (ie, the image they clicked on) works fine but the template that is added, events do not.  here is my code:

template Function

```
template:function (renderOptions) {
//various case statements to determine which template to use
//returns the name of the template to use
return 'activityImages';
}
```

the above template has html code for the view.  In the end, i have this:

```
<div id ="imageViewerDiv" class = "imageViewerDiv"></div>
```

I then add the model, in the templateContext function:

```
templateContext:function (renderOptions) {
 // builds out a list of objects and returns it to be used in the template

}
```

Code for Image Click Event:

```
  viewImage: function(e){
    try{
        var template = window.app.getTemplate('activityImageViewer')
        var that = this;           
        //other variables defined here

        //I am trying to create an effect that pops up a modal div, with the image in it
        //in order for me to cover the entire app, i have to append this div to the body
        $(document).find('body').append($("#imageViewerDiv"))
        var temp = template({
            //variables I need passed here
        });

        this.addImageToViewer(temp);
    }catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
},

//here I add a partial template to the main template.  this is where events fail to bind.
//in my template i have this, within a div, inside a table 

<div id = "prevImgGalleryImg" name = "prevImgGalleryImg" style="float: right; padding-left: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Prev</div>

addImageToViewer: function(template){
    try{
        var that = this;
        var temp = template;
        $(document).find('body').append($("#imageViewerDiv"))
        $("#imageViewerDiv").append(template);

        //I add events here, as they do not bind any other way          

        $("#prevImgGalleryImg").click(function(){
           //cant get this or that here
            alert('test')
        });

    }catch(e){
        throw e;
    }

},
```

To add events, i do this, but it does not work:

```
events:{
  //my events
    'click .prevImgGalleryImg': 'prevImgGalleryImg'

},

prevImgGalleryImg: function(e){
  alert('test');
},
```

**Solution:**

After some struggles, I figured it out.  When I was adding the div, like this:

```
 $(document).find('body').append($("#imageViewerDiv"))
```

I should have been adding it like this:

```
  this.$el.append($("#imageViewerDiv"))
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Backbone functions are typically on the backbone model itself, not added manually with jQuery.

Comment: Please provide more code, where you try to use this/that?

Comment: Ive updated my question with more code, to help show what I am doing.

Comment: Most of the code you've posted here doesn't look relevant to the problem you're describing. Where are your event handlers? Define "does not work" for us—are exceptions being thrown? What behavior are you expecting versus what you're seeing?

Comment: In the `events` object you say isn't working you're listening to `.prevImgGalleryImg`, a class. In the jQuery `click` you're attaching to `#prevImgGalleryImg`, an id.  If you redefine the events block to 'click #prevImgGalleryImg', does it work?

Comment: Hello, I tried using .prevImgGalleryImg as well as #prevImgGalleryImg but neither works.  And by not working, i mean nothing happens.  no error and nothing is fired

Comment: The event block is also pointing to a prevImgGalleryImg function. Can you post the source for that?

Comment: Added, but they are just empty.  I use the browsers debugger and can see that the event is never called

Comment: Could this be because the div I want to add the event to isn't added until later, after initialize and render?

Comment: figured it out.  When adding the div to the view, i should be doing it to the $el not document.  I'll append this to my question

Answer (score 0):

Your backbone should look something like this:

```
events:{
    'click .buttonOne': 'eventOne',  //works
    'click .buttonTwo': 'eventTwo'  //doesnt work

},

eventOne: function () {
    console.log(this);
},

eventTwo: function () {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Now you can access this correctly. Not sure why you we using jquery to attach events.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not seem to work in my partial template.  I've added more code to my question, if it helps

Answer (score 0):

See [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) and [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll).

Calling `_.bind`/`_.bindAll` from your view's constructor/initialize function will enforce the correct `this` context:

```
var MyCustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...,
    events: {
        'click .buttonOne': 'eventOne',
        'click .buttonTwo': 'eventTwo'
    },
    initialize: function( options ) {
        ...;

        _.bindAll(this, 'eventOne', 'eventTwo');
    }
    ...,
    eventOne: function( event ) {
        // 'this' will always reference MyCustomView
    },
    eventTwo: function( event ) {
        // 'this' will always reference MyCustomView
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still does not work.  I've added more code to my question, if that helps

Comment: Yes, i've tried adding the bindall on initialize but this still does not fire.  could this be due to the fact that the button that I want to fire doesn't actually get added until after initialize?  The button is part of a partial template that gets added after render (by another click event)